# Is the [tail] tag telling tall tales?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are currently just over 1,000 questions tagged with [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail). This tag is, IMHO, both (extremely) ambiguous and (mostly) unnecessary. Should we remove it?

Assessment of the [formal burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/616624):

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**

Even the tag Wiki (and excerpt) offer two different meanings (part of a linked-list and a Unix/Linux file-system command), and many of the questions using it refer to completely different things, such as a type (brand?) of USB device. So: **No, it is not unambiguous.**

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

That depends on which of the concepts you consider. Unix/Linux commands are arguably off-topic, as are questions about specific device types.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I would argue that, in the potentially valid use-case (i.e., as part of a linked-list), the tag is irrelevant and serves no real purpose in terms of clarification of the question or when searching for help.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Most certainly not! In addition to the uses already mentioned, it also appears on a number of questions about the Python/Pandas `.tail()` function.

So, should we remove the tag, or possibly (somehow) disambiguate it and/or its usage guidelines?

Comment: *Wags tail in appreciation*

Comment: "Let's `tail` off"

Comment: I'm sure there will also be questions about tail recursion, and questions about other list-oriented languages than Pandas like Prolog (and Haskell IIRC?) where it's a frequent and as such well-defined term.

Comment: @triplee Cases like that could be handled by disambiguation ... and there already *is* a `tail-recursion` tag.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think [all the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail+recursion) tagged with `[tail][recursion]` can be simply retagged to `[tail-recursion]`, but that's just down 32 questions. lot and lots more to go

Comment: Sure, just pointing out some variations which I felt were missing from your exposition.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Splitting \[head\]-ache](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419386) I was actually writing the question when I noticed yours. I thought the timing of both of these showing up is amusing.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, I'm not going to call it, but it's likely a coin-flip as to which of our questions will get the best score. xD

Comment: Agree with 1 & 4, not sure I agree with 2 or 3.  For 2) Unix scripting is programming, so questions about how to do something via Unix scripting are on topic, provided they're sufficiently complex as programs.  (A "tail" tag for linked lists seems useless though.)  For 3) 'tail` is a scripting tool that can be used in multiple shells, it's reasonable to ask about using `tail` in [tag:bash] or [tag:csh] or [tag:ksh].  As such I think it might add useful information to a scripting question.  Maybe we need a [tag:tail-command] for legit scripting use cases?

Comment: @VLAZ notably there is already a `[unix-head]` tag that would be appropriate for disambiguating the command in your other question. There is not a corresponding `[unix-tail]` tag, however.

Comment: @dbc tail is not a "scripting". It's a binary that you can call from anywhere. Your bash/zsh/tsh script, python, C, etc. It's akin to saying that dpkg is programming because you call it from a shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a retag all again. I wrote an opinion piece on one of these before.

In this case, would write to remove everything but I can't because I can't come up with a better tag for the tail of the list meaning last n entries (most [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail) questions and some others). If somebody does, I will change my opinion to remove everything.

- [unix-tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-tail) for questions involving the tail command (tag doesn't exist but [unix-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-head) does, so make it)
- [tail-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail-recursion) (optionally with [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion): use your best judgment on the question) for tail recursion questions
- [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail) referring to the last entry of the list should just have the tail tag removed.
- same for [double-linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-linked-list)
- some [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail) are misspelled [tails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tails)

In theory, a tag could go to [tail-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail-call) but I didn't find any.

And then there's this question: [Array-based queueing lock - tail overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635947/array-based-queueing-lock-tail-overflow) It needs work. Clearly there's enough context that somebody was able to answer it, but as it stands it's just not good. What even is `tail` here?

Comment: "unix-tail for questions involving the tail command (tag doesn't exist but unix-head does, so make it)" no, lets just close those questions. Command line commands usage isn't on topic for this site. If you need to ask questions for those, SO is not the place for it.

Comment: @Braiam: You will lose that debate. There's a lot of them, and the design of unix scripting is deliberately designed to blur the line between user and programmer.

Comment: If I lose it, so be it, but it's still what it should be. A bad idea doesn't become a good one because it's popular, the same applies in the opposite way.