# Splitting [head]-ache

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/head) tag description is *right now* referring to two completely different concepts. Here is the usage guidance:

> Html  element or unix command. Check if you should use html-head or unix-head instead.

And the tag wiki that goes with it:

> The `<head>` element is a container for all the head elements.
>
> The  element must include a title for the document, and can include scripts, styles, meta information, and more.
>
> The following elements can go inside the  element:
>
> ```
> <title> (this element is required in the head section)
> <style>
> <base>
> <link>
> <meta>
> <script>
> <noscript>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> `head` is also a unix command which displays the first lines of a file. It's counterpart which displays the last lines is `tail` ([tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail)).
>
> *Example*: `head -n 10 file` will output first 10 lines of `file`.

There is no overlap between the HTML `<head>` tag and the `head` tool in Unix. Even then the tag is *also* used for:

- Git questions where [HEAD](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#ref_the_ref) is involved
- The head of a list data structure
- HTTP [HEAD method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)

That brings the total of the usages to five. There might be more times [head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/head) was applied but not for either of these five.

At the very least, the tag needs to be disambiguated. It might also need to be removed entirely (after splitting) as it is too ambiguous.

---

For reference, here are [the burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

**No**: there are at least five distinct usages for "head". With no meaningful overlap between them other than the general linguistic notion of "beginning".

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

**Yes**: each of the (at least) five separate things named "head" are on-topic for Stack Overflow. They are programming concepts. Although, the Unix tool `head` might be a stretch. The [unix-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-head) tag has 5 questions in it. Of which I would say 4 are more at home on Super User or the Unix stacks. The one which might be a Stack Overflow question is: [How do I get java to exit when piped to head](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11695500).

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

**Maybe**: Depends on which usage it is, really.

- Unix tool `head`: maybe not. The questions about *using* `head` are for Unix or Super User. I am not sure if there are many, if any, questions about programming that involve the Unix `head` tool. The question above is good but I am not sure it is a question *about* `head`. It just happened to use it. The same question can be re-contextualised as "How to handle a situation where standard output disappears while using it in Java?". The question is about the `head` tool destroying the output pipe when enough data is received while Java just continues trying to print to it. Same situation might arise under different circumstances.
- HTML `<head>` tag: maybe yes. Although, I would expect few questions are specifically about the `<head>` tag. A lot more would concern HTML in general or interaction between HTML and other technologies, e.g., JavaScript.

  I would personally not consider questions about the `<head>` tag to be much different from questions about just HTML but perhaps there is a meaningful case where the tag makes a good distinction.
- Git HEAD reference: probably not. I honestly cannot fathom what a question very specifically about the HEAD reference would be. It is just a pointer to the current branch. It is not really special other than a slight convenience when using Git.

  I would expect any question that *involves* the HEAD reference to be actually about *using Git*. Hence the HEAD is a red herring. If somebody is trying to do `git rebase HEAD~4` (to rebase the last four commits) or `git show HEAD~4` (to examine the fifth from last commit) or `git commit --squash=HEAD~4` (to commit and schedule for squashing with the fifth from last commit) they all use HEAD but are about `rebase`, `show`, and `commit` respectively. Or probably just Git related, depending on context.

  The syntax `~<number>` is not specific to HEAD, either. It is how revisions can be specified in Git: `develop~4` can be used to refer to the fifth from last commit on the develop branch. Or `a5d27f6656637a867fcdb5d806d81d3036fa22d1~4` to refer to fifth commit back from the commit with the hash `a5d27f6656637a867fcdb5d806d81d3036fa22d1`. So, questions about *that* are also generic Git questions.
- The head of a list data structure: yes.
- HTTP HEAD method: yes.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

**Absolutely not.**

Comment: Off with the [head], as the Queen of Hearts would say.

Comment: Go a[head] with burnination.

Comment: i still wish that every burnification question would be punished by - 200000 rep, so that there would be less of them all together. the tag wiki explain it well and so it is not need to burn it, also you can't synopsize it. as it can be used for both, so it is perfect as it is

Comment: @nbk there are *five* distinct, unrelated, non-overlapping usages of the tag. It is not at all "perfect". The tag wiki doesn't mention three of them, for a start. Nor should a tag be used for multiple distinct things, either.

Comment: @nbk: [I] [hear] [you] [like] [lots] [of] [tags].

Comment: @kjhughes i have now 732 tags in my profile and like to get even more, sadly n conjunction with sql you get only few new tags every day. And yes tags are to find the questions you like, and help navigate through the thousands of new questions every day, so as i see it more tags means better filtering for interesting questions, and so i can learn every day new things

Comment: @VLAZ there could be twenty, which means the wiki has to be improved and show all 20 of them. i didn't know there were five, but it seams that you are perfect for the improving job

Comment: @nbk "*which means the wiki has to be improved and show all 20 of them*" No.

Comment: @nbk with that logic why have tags at all? just stick the tag "question" on it and have wiki list every possible meaning

Comment: @Nifim the ae some tags that point in every direction take for example sql as tag alone it doesn't help as every rdms has its own logic, to process the sql string, still the tag points in the right direction, what the question is about, the same goes for HEAD without another tag it becomes a good question, besides my logic is impeccable

Comment: @nbk that seems like a good comparison, `sql` tells you something about the question it involves sql, `head` tells you tells you the question involves `head`. now if i know some sql i can probably fumble through some foreign, to me, sql logic... Not sure i could say the same for `head`. if i know about a git head i dont think could answer ABSOLUTLY anything about the other `head` topic items they are completely unrelated other than sharing a name.

Comment: @Nifim but ou know by seeing the tag HEAD what it is about, if git isn't you cup of tee, don't drink it, but still you would understand, what the question is about.

Comment: @nbk My point is you dont, it might be about http or html or the unix command, `head` does not tell you what the question is about or whether it is something in your "wheel house"

Comment: @nbk In the same vein, [question] is about questions and if it isn't your cup of tea, don't drink it.

Comment: None of the implied usages strikes me as useful. HTML head spec is two paragraph long, html alone should suffice. The unix tool isn't on topic (also pretty simple). Head component of some data structure? Why not using the name of the data structure (if it's defined) instead? Or the language/framework where it's found? HTTP head method? Why not using HTTP? Are people reading the same help center as me when it says "you should only create new tags when [...] your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site" Those usages have been topics asked before.